# Google Docs API for creating invoice containing table of variable number of rows

Tags: dynamic, google-docs-api, mailmerge

I have a template file for my invoice with a table with sample row, but I want to add more rows dynamically based on a given array size, and write the cell values from the array...

Template's photo

[image: 1]

I've been struggling for almost 3 days now.

Is there any easy way to accomplish that?
Here's the template file: [Link to the Docs file(template)](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZiLGvPwVYUuhf9UQFr47AekFwR6fWqfwoRDCV1TyHBI/edit#heading=h.ebjvaihivdem)

And here's a few sample arrays of input data to be replaced in the Template file:

```
[
    [
        "Sample item 1s",
        "Sample Quantity 1",
        "Sample price 1",
        "Sample total 1"
    ],
    [
        "Sample item 2",
        "Sample Quantity 2",
        "Sample price 2",
        "Sample total 2"
    ],
    [
        "Sample item 3",
        "Sample Quantity 3",
        "Sample price 3",
        "Sample total 3"
    ],
]
```

Now, the length of the parent array can vary depending on the number of items in the invoice, and that's the only problem that I'm struggling with.

And... Yeah, this is a duplicate question, I've found another question on the same topic, but looking at the answers and comments, everyone is commenting that they don't understand the question whereas it looks perfectly clear for me.

[Google Docs Invoice template with dynamically items row from Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66593181/google-docs-invoice-template-with-dynamically-items-row-from-google-sheets)

I think the person who asked the question have already quit from it. :(

By the way I am using the API for PHP (Google API Client Library for PHP), and code for replacing dummy text a Google Docs Document by the actual data is given below:

```
public function replaceTexts(array $replacements, string $document_id) {
    # code...
    $req = new Docs\BatchUpdateDocumentRequest();
    // var_dump($replacements);
    // die();
    foreach ($replacements as $replacement) {
        $target = new Docs\SubstringMatchCriteria();
        $target->text = "{{" . $replacement["targetText"] . "}}";
        $target->setMatchCase(false);
        $req->setRequests([
            ...$req->getRequests(),
            new Docs\Request([
                "replaceAllText" => [
                    "replaceText" => $replacement["newText"],
                    "containsText" => $target
                ]
            ]),
        ]);
    }

    return $this->docs_service->documents->batchUpdate(
        $document_id,
        $req
    );
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `And here's a few sample arrays of input data to be replaced in the Template file:` and your `Template's photo`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Tanaike, actually in the template you can see a table with a single template row {{item name}}, {{item quantity}} etc.
Now, based on the the number of elements in the input array, the number of table rows should increase or decrease.

Is there any build-in function for doing that? Like a function that takes an array of table tows and create table accordingly? Or anything similar to the replaceText, but for tables of variable number of rows?

Comment: Thank you for replying. As one more question, can I ask you about the relationship between your showing script and the array of "And here's a few sample arrays of input data to be replaced in the Template file:"?

Comment: @Tanaike that code for *replacing* dummy text with another text was mentioned here to specify what type of function I am expecting to find from Google API client.

If there's any function similar to that textReplacement request, it'd be very useful.

I've searched in many websites and YouTube, but they're all showing the code for replacing dummy texts only :(

Comment: All the articles and videos have title like "Using Google Docs API for programmatically creating invoices from template Docs", but none of 'em explains a thing about the case when the invoice have a table of variable number of rows.   :|

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, I think that it is required to add the rows by the length of the data array. But, unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and the array of "And here's a few sample arrays of input data to be replaced in the Template file:"? This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution would be the following

1. First prep the document by removing every row from the table apart from the title.
2. Get the full document tree from the Google Docs API.
   This would be a simple call with the document id

   `$doc = $service->documents->get($documentId);`
3. Traverse the document object returned to get to the table and then find the location of the right cell. This could be done by looping through the elements in the `body` object until one with the right `table` field is found. Note that this may not necessarily be the first one since in your template, the section with the `{{CustomerName}}` placeholder is also a table. So you may have to find a table that has the first cell with a text value of "Item".
4. Add a new row to the table. This is done by creating a request with the shape:

   [
   'insertTableRow' => [
   'tableCellLocation' => [
   'rowIndex' => 1,
   'columnIndex' => 1,
   'tableStartLocation' => [
   'index' => 177
   ]
   ]
   ]
   ]

The `tableStartLocation->index` element is the paragraph index of the cell to be entered, i.e. `body->content[i]->table->startIndex`. Send the request.

5. Repeat steps 2 and 3 to get the updated `$doc` object, and then access the newly created cell i.e. `body->content[i]->table->tableRows[j]->tableCells[k]->content->paragraph->elements[l]->startIndex`.
6. Send a request to update the text content of the cell at the location of the startIndex from 5 above, i.e.

   [
   'insertText' => [
   'location' => [
   'index' => 206,
   ]
   ],
   'text' => 'item_1'
   ]
   ]
7. Repeat step 5 but access the next cell. Note that after each update you need to fetch an updated version of the document object because the indexes change after inserts.

To be honest, this approach is pretty cumbersome, and it's probably more efficient to insert all the data into a spreadsheet and then embed the spreadsheet into your word document. Information on that can be found here [How to insert an embedded sheet via Google Docs API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64705204/how-to-insert-an-embedded-sheet-via-google-docs-api).

As a final note, I created a copy of your template and used the "*Try this method*" feature in the API documentation to validate my approach so some of the PHP syntax may be a bit off, but I hope you get the general idea.